# Can't import a Go local module when module name starts with github.com, otherwise works fine

Tags: go

I tried using the following command for my Go module locally.

```
go mod init mymodule/api
```

When I try to import files locally, like `import "mymodule/api/routes"`, it works. However, I tried changing my Go module's name by deleting the initial `go.mod` file and running this command.

```
go mod init github.com/myrepo/project/api
```

Then, when I import the file in one of my modules by doing `import "github.com/myrepo/project/api/routes"`, it doesn't work. It doesn't try to import the module locally, instead it tries to fetch a module from `github.com`.

The exact error message is the following.

```
github.com/myrepo/project/api/routes: cannot find module providing package github.com/myrepo/project/api/routes: module github.com/myrepo/project/api/routes: git ls-remote -q origin in C:\Users\R\go\pkg\mod\cache\vcs\8c9cab82d2eef4d5003b0ef7010fbbba91353c1368fe1a69d6c6a8fbfa8c8eb5: exit status 128:
        remote: Repository not found.
        fatal: repository 'github.com/myrepo/project/api' not found
```

Can anyone let me know how I can rename my Go module to start with a github.com prefix and still load the modules locally? Or is this the expected behavior?

Comment: See also: [workspaces](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces)

Comment: From my experience, workspaces are not yet a fully baked feature as [not all Go tooling commands support them](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50750)- currently figuring out how to use `go.mod` replacements instead.

Answer (score 2):

**DEVELOPMENT STATE:**

When you wanted to develop both or debug both of the packages.
from the Golang documentation:

> replace directive replaces the contents of a specific version of a module, or all versions of a module, with contents found elsewhere. The replacement may be specified with either another module path and version, or a platform-specific file path.

so you can use replace command for this purpose, by replacing the exact package address with your local package address:

```
replace (
    github.com/myrepo/project/api => ../myLocalRepo/Project/Api
)
```

for more information about `replace`, read this documentation: https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace

**PRODUCTION STATE:**

but if you wanted to use it in production. it depends on your package, if your package is private on GitHub: the most specific option would be setting `GOPRIVATE` to match the path of your module exactly. like this:

```
GOPRIVATE=github.com/your_github_username/project/apit
```

Comment: Seems to work, but is this the only way to make this work? I've never seen this mentioned anywhere else, so I'm afraid it's not a common solution.

Comment: @Richard in the development state, yes it's the way. but in production, it's not a standard solution.

Comment: How would this be handled in the production state? Obviously, the local repo (local path) might be different when collaborators clone my git repo.

Comment: @Richard I'll update my answer for the production state